# Sort() In Opencv+Python

Tags: python, sorting, opencv

ive got a problem that i cant solve. Im trying to make a temporal median filter using the method sort(), but i simply cant do it. This is the simpliest test i tried:

```
import cv2

def sortExample():

    img = cv2.imread("guitar.jpg")
    cv2.sort(img, cv2.SORT_ASCENDING)

sortExample()
```

And the error:

> cv2.sort(img, cv2.SORT_ASCENDING)
>   cv2.error: ......\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:2367: error: (-215) src.dims <= 2 && src.channels() == 1 && func != 0

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the checks `src.dims <= 2 && src.channels() == 1 && func != 0` failed (maybe if it was less cluttered you would have no trouble seeing that ?). In special, it is telling you the number of channels is not 1.

So you can either consider one of the channels or convert the image to, for example, grayscale: `x = cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`.

Comment: yes mate you did that... now that i think about it, its really stupid having the image in RGB. Thanks (:

Comment: A little bit of a necropost, but if you wanted to sort the image by one of the colour channels, how would you do that?